# How to trigger printer in IOS with my app?

Tags: gwt, ios7, uiwebview, cross-browser, uiwebviewdelegate

I'm developing an IOS application, using GWT. I want to trigger print functionality in app.

> `Window.print();`

The above code is working fine in **Safari browser but not from my app.**

Please provide me the valuable suggestion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following source code:
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer

If you are using Phonegap/Cordova, then it's quite straightforward. Otherwise, just copy and paste the code from the plugin